# Can I Modify Facebook Footer To Add "Terms Of Service" And "Privacy Policy" Links For My Facebook App?

Tags: facebook, user-interface

"Terms of Service" and "Privacy Policy" links are displayed only while adding an app in Facebook.

Can I modify the Facebook footer to display "Terms of Service" and "Privacy Policy" links on all the pages?

Answer (score 0):

try navigate to http://developers.facebook.com/apps/#APPID#/advanced
and type TOS/PP URLs at the bottom of the page

Comment: I've already set them. As I mentioned they will be displayed only while adding the app but not in the footer while using the app.